# How we can get a list of all the updates and patches which have been installed inside sharePoint farm 2013 and 2016 on-premises

Tags: 2013, administration, cumulative-update, patching, sharepoint-farm

I am working on some SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 on-premises farms. and on some farms we install a full CU each 6 month, then we run the product configuration wizard. for those farms we do the following as part of the backup policy:-

1. Back up the full farm using `Backup-SPFarm` on daily basis.
2. also we backup each site collection separately.

now for the farms which we install full CU each 6 months, we can be sure if the sharepoint server crashed for a reason or another, we can build a fresh sharepoint farm, install the same CU which we install on the original crashed farm, restore the farm.i did some test and everything worked well.

but on some farms, our customers install security updates each 1-3 months, and those security updates contain some sharepoint security updates, which might affect the farm build number. of course for those customers we mentioned to them, that they need to run the product configuration wizard, after installing any sharepoint security updates.. but for those farms we can easily lose track of the current sharepoint farm patches and updates. For example let say the farm crashes and we wanted to create a fresh sharepoint farm to restore the backup-ed farm, then we will not be sure of what are the latest patches and updates that were installed on the crashed server..

So my question is, if there is a way we can extract all the sharepoint patches and updates that are currently installed inside SharePoint  2013 or 2016 farm? so if this farm crashes we can go back to this list to know exactly what we should install inside the fresh farm which we might need to create, to restore the backup-ed farm..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this. One is to review Installed Updates in Programs and Features on a server in the farm (this assumes all SharePoint servers are properly patched with the same patches). This will give you a list of KBs.

Alternatively, I wrote a script some time ago to get some of that product information.

[SharePoint Product Information](https://github.com/Nauplius/SharePointProductInformation)

As an aside, backing up Content Databases and Site Collections is redundant. You only need to do one :-)

Comment: now i am backuping the site collections to cover some scenarios such as if the site admin did a faulty setting or enable a features, etc. so in this case we can just restore a single site collection, while the content database will cover other scenarios. now i know that i can review the installed updates from the server control panel , but i want to do this using a script, as each server will have different patches paths ..

Comment: ... so will running this script https://github.com/Nauplius/SharePointProductInformation shows all the info we need to build a new farm from scratch which will be 100% identical to the original farm ? so if the source farm crashes, then we can build a new farm based on the info we have from the script https://github.com/Nauplius/SharePointProductInformation and then we can restore the farm inside the new shareoint farm?

Comment: You don't need to backup a site collection to individually restore it. You can use an unattached Content Database restore instead, which is why backing up a site collection is redundant. You need to evaluate the script to make sure it fits your needs.

Comment: can you adivce what do you mean by `You need to evaluate the script to make sure it fits your needs.`?? now if i run this script `Get-SPProductInformation | select displayname,islatest,patch | ft -a` will i get all the patches and updates which have been installed inside sharepoint? and i can refer to the result to build a new farm incase the current farm crashed...

Comment: I can't elaborate on seeing if it meets your needs. If it does, great, if it doesn't, look at Programs and Features instead.